# How update disconnected NiFi-Registry?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

There are NiFi and NiFi-Registry on the server, which is not connected and I'm not able to connect to NiFi-Registry through local NiFi instance.But I can access NiFi and NiFi-Registry through remote desktop.

Another version of NiFi and NiFi-Registry are installed on my local development system.
Is there any way to offline update(sync) remote NiFi-Registry flows and apply new update to remote NiFi?

[image]

Comment: This is what you want: https://pierrevillard.com/2018/04/09/automate-workflow-deployment-in-apache-nifi-with-the-nifi-registry/

Comment: Thanks @Sdairs for your response.
According to this (great) document, it seems I have to create the buckets and flow in production registry before deploy any updates to. I am looking for a method to deploy all buckets and flows to production all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to sync from a local registry instance on your development workstation to a production registry instance in a way that wouldn't be very risky to your production environment. What I've done on teams that use the NiFi Registry for active development is we just connect our development machines' NiFi instances to the central repository and have a team-wide rule of "thous shalt not commit without a two person review." Worked well even on a team that often fought like cats and dogs over changes.

Note: every team I've worked on like this has used one Registry for all environments. That's the easiest way to promote from one to the next in an Agile way.

Comment: Thanks for your guide.
The problem is I have not access to production registry. It is disconnected server.